# count the number of uses of each of the objects in another table

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class FirstTable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)


class SecondTable(models.Model):
    examples = models.ManyToManyField(FirstTable)
```

I have a function which counts how many times `FirstTable` is used in SecondTable's examples field:

```
data = {}
for i in FirstTable.objects.all():
    data[i.name] = SecondTable.objects.filter(examples__exact=i).count()
```

but is it possible to get the same data with one request? (aggregate or annotate ways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
from django.db.models import Count

FirstTable.objects.annotate(examples_count=Count('secondtable')).values('name', 'examples_count')
```

The output will be:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'Name1', 'examples_count': 3}, {'name': 'Name2', 'examples_count': 10}, ..., >
```

Comment: it should be `secondtable`. Please see edited answer.